Unit testing async void (fire-and-forget) methods
I am writing tests in MSTest for a WPF application that contains calls to async void methods (fire-and-forget pattern).
My goal is to run this code synchronously during tests.
Is this possible?
I have tried with a "synchronous" SynchronizationContext:
public class SynchronousSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<(SendOrPostCallback, object)> _workItems = new ConcurrentQueue<(SendOrPostCallback, object)>();
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _workItemsAvailable = new AutoResetEvent(false);


    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext.Post(), start");

        // Execute the callback immediately
        d(state);

        Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext.Post(), end");
    }

    /* enqueues the work item to be completed later:
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext.Post()");

        _workItems.Enqueue((d, state));
        _workItemsAvailable.Set();
    }
    */

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext.Send()");

        d(state);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext.Run()");

        while (_workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem))
        {
            workItem.Item1(workItem.Item2);
        }
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext.Complete()");

        while (_workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("SynchronousSynchronizationContext, execute callback");

            // execute callback.
            // The workItem is a tuple where Item1 is the callback and Item2 is the state object.
            workItem.Item1(workItem.Item2);
        }
    }
}

But it does not work. The Post() method does not run the callback synchronously like I want.
Instead I have to call Complete() explicitly at various points in my test method:
private SynchronousSynchronizationContext _syncContext;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{    
    _syncContext = new SynchronousSynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(_syncContext);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTest_ReturnsData()
{
    // ACT
    MyTest();

    // Finish all fire-and-forget tasks:
    _syncContext.Complete();

    // ASSERT
    ...

}

Is there a way to run the code synchronously without having to call Complete()?

async void is not "fire-and-forget" - it's "fire-and-crash" or "fire-and-leak-resources" - so unless and except you're in WinForms or WPF where there's a synchronization-context. In library-code you must never use async void. Your compiler should be giving you dire-warnings about your code as-is...

"Is this possible?" - No.

this is a WPF app.

MSTest does not activate or run within WPF's synchronization context.

that's why i tried to supply a custom SynchronizationContext.

"// Finish all fire-and-forget tasks:"  That doesn't sound like forget to me.

of course i only want to do this in my unit tests.

Write two methods: async Task, which contains all the logic, and async void wrapper, which simply calls the async Task method and awaits the result.
Use async void in the application. Use async Task in tests.

I don't get how Complete helps at all if you don't Enqueue anything in Post?!

Related: Wait for an async void method.

​@Dai it is actually possible to await an async void method, but it's so tricky that I wouldn't recommend it to anyone.

@IvanPetrov look at the commented version. The code is only an example of what I have tried.

We could rely on the async void state machine calling SynchronizationContext.OperationStarted and SynchronizationContext.OperationCompleted to track the async operation and catch exceptions. As Servy commented, this is a bit challenging because the async void method can itself call async void methods in its body, but I think we can get it working with simply reusing the same SynchronizationContext and maintaining a count of active operations.
To simplify the use we wrap everything in a Task returning static method call such as:
await AsyncVoidRunner.RunAsync(AsyncVoidMethod);

This will wait for the main async void method (and all nested) to complete and will capture all exceptions and rethrow either a single or an AggregateException with the correct stack trace.
Also, I think it is desirable to be able to specify a SynchronizationContext such as the default WPF or a custom one that we wrap around but let it do its job otherwise.
This is a possible implementation:
public static class AsyncVoidRunner {

    public static async Task RunAsync(
       Action asyncVoidMethod,
       bool continuationsOnCurrentContext = true) {

        var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        var asyncSyncContext = new AsyncVoidSyncContext(continuationsOnCurrentContext ?
        capturedContext : null);

        // we have to set it before we call the asyncVoidMethod
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(asyncSyncContext);

        try {
            asyncVoidMethod();

            // fake async to avoid possible dead-locks
            await Task.Run(() => asyncSyncContext.WaitForCompletion());
        } finally {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(capturedContext);
        }
    }

    public static async Task RunAsync(
    Action asyncVoidMethod,
    SynchronizationContext syncContext) {

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(syncContext);

        var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        var asyncSyncContext = new AsyncVoidSyncContext(syncContext);

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(asyncSyncContext);

        try {
            asyncVoidMethod();
            // fake async to avoid possible dead-locks
            // TODO: possible rewrite of WaitForCompletion to be async
            await Task.Run(() => asyncSyncContext.WaitForCompletion());
        } finally {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(capturedContext);
        }
    }

    private sealed class AsyncVoidSyncContext : SynchronizationContext {


        List<ExceptionDispatchInfo> _exceptionsInfos = new List<ExceptionDispatchInfo>();
        SynchronizationContext _mainContext;
        
        ManualResetEventSlim _operationStartedCalled = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        int _activeOps;
        ManualResetEventSlim _lastOperationCompleted = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        int _pendingPosts;
        ManualResetEventSlim _noPendingPosts = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);

        public AsyncVoidSyncContext(SynchronizationContext syncContext) {
            _mainContext = syncContext;
        }

        // async void state machine is calling this when it starts execution
        public override void OperationStarted() {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation Started on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            Interlocked.Increment(ref _activeOps);

            // for non-async void methods check
            // to avoid endless blocking in WaitForCompletion()
            if (_operationStartedCalled.IsSet == false) {
                _operationStartedCalled.Set();
            }
        }

        // async void state machine is calling this when finished
        public override void OperationCompleted() {
            Console.WriteLine("OperationCompleted on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _activeOps) == 0) {
            
                // now at this point we could still have 
                // oustanding Post that throws exception
                // becasuse SetException does THrowAsync
                // which is Post
                // then becaues it returns immediately
                // it calls OperationCompleted...
                // even though we haven't had the chance of processing everything
                // -> we maintain a counter and event for outstandings posts
                // which we check in WaitForCompletion
                _lastOperationCompleted.Set();
            }
        }

        public void WaitForCompletion() {
            // short wait for initiation
            // if not started not async void method
            if (_operationStartedCalled.Wait(10) == false) {
                throw new Exception("Non void method");
                // TODO: or just return?
            };

            _lastOperationCompleted.Wait();
            // state machine is Posting the Exceptions Async
            // and marking Complete before we have a change to process
            // all posts (relevant if we use another SyncContext)
            _noPendingPosts.Wait();
            
            switch (_exceptionsInfos.Count) {
                case 0: return;
                case 1:
                    // TODO: just throw ??
                    _exceptionsInfos[0].Throw();
                    break;
                case > 1:
                    var aggregateException = new AggregateException(
                    _exceptionsInfos.Select(e => e.SourceException));
                    throw aggregateException;
            }
        }

        // just dispatching to PostInternal (see comment there)
        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _pendingPosts);
            _noPendingPosts.Reset();
            
            if (_mainContext == null) {
                // we execute main logic in-line
                PostInternal(state, d, this);
            } else {
                // more transparent capture (instead of inline lambda)
                // we let the main Context execute the main-logic
                // possibly on another thread (e.g. UI thread)
                
                // chcek if outstanding
                _mainContext.Post(this.PostCaptureHelper, (state, d));
            }
        }

        void PostCaptureHelper(object valueTUple) {
            switch (valueTUple) {
                case (object s, SendOrPostCallback d):
                    PostInternal(s, d, this);
                    return;
                default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        // we are possibly called on a thread pool thread
        // coming back from an async operation (i.e. Task.Delay)
        // we need to set the SynchronizationContext to this
        // before we continue
        // so it is captured in the state machines of other async methods 
        // we call from this point forward
        /*  await Task.Delay(100);
            // we are here with no SyncContext to capture
            // if we don't do that explicitly
            asyncMethod();
        */
        // in the current async method / state machine
        static void PostInternal(object state, SendOrPostCallback d,
          AsyncVoidSyncContext asyncVoidContext) {

            var captureContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            try {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(asyncVoidContext);
                d(state);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                asyncVoidContext._exceptionsInfos.Add(ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex));
            } finally {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(captureContext);
                if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref asyncVoidContext._pendingPosts)==0){
                    asyncVoidContext._noPendingPosts.Set();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

To test we could use the the following methods:
async void AsyncVoidMethod() {
    NestedAsyncVoid();
    Console.WriteLine("AsyncVoidMethod on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(250);
    Console.WriteLine("AsyncVoidMethod on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    NestedAsyncVoid(); 
    throw new Exception("---AsyncVoidMethod EXCEPTION"); 
}

async void NestedAsyncVoid() {
    await Task.Delay(100);
    MoreNestedAsyncVoid(); 
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("NestedAsyncVoid on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    throw new Exception("----NestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION"); 
}

async void MoreNestedAsyncVoid() {
    await Task.Delay(200);
    Console.WriteLine("MoreNestedAsyncVoid on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    throw new Exception("-----MoreNestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION");
}

Two obvious scenarios are with/without another context. For simulation purposes I've picked the SingleThreadSynchronizationContext which is demonstrated in this blogpost by Stephen Toub
async Task SingleThreadSyncContextTest() {
    var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    try {
        var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);

        var t = AsyncVoidRunner.RunAsync(AsyncVoidMethod);
        var continueTask = t.ContinueWith(
            t => {
                syncCtx.Complete();
            }, TaskScheduler.Default);

        syncCtx.RunOnCurrentThread();
        await t;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex is AggregateException aggEx) {
            foreach (var element in aggEx.InnerExceptions) {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Message);
            }
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    } finally {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(capturedContext);
    }
}

async Task NoSyncContext() {
    try {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
        await AsyncVoidRunner.RunAsync(AsyncVoidMethod, true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex is AggregateException aggEx) {
            foreach (var element in aggEx.InnerExceptions) {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Message);
            }
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

Finally:
await SingleThreadSyncContextTest();
Console.WriteLine();
await NoSyncContext();

and the results:
Operation Started on thread: 1
Operation Started on thread: 1
AsyncVoidMethod on thread: 1
Operation Started on thread: 1
NestedAsyncVoid on thread: 1
OperationCompleted on thread: 1
AsyncVoidMethod on thread: 1
Operation Started on thread: 1
OperationCompleted on thread: 1
MoreNestedAsyncVoid on thread: 1
OperationCompleted on thread: 1
Operation Started on thread: 1
NestedAsyncVoid on thread: 1
OperationCompleted on thread: 1
MoreNestedAsyncVoid on thread: 1
OperationCompleted on thread: 1
----NestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION
---AsyncVoidMethod EXCEPTION
-----MoreNestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION
----NestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION
-----MoreNestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION

Operation Started on thread: 1
Operation Started on thread: 1
AsyncVoidMethod on thread: 1
Operation Started on thread: 25
NestedAsyncVoid on thread: 25
OperationCompleted on thread: 25
AsyncVoidMethod on thread: 15
Operation Started on thread: 15
OperationCompleted on thread: 15
MoreNestedAsyncVoid on thread: 25
OperationCompleted on thread: 25
Operation Started on thread: 25
NestedAsyncVoid on thread: 27
OperationCompleted on thread: 27
MoreNestedAsyncVoid on thread: 25
OperationCompleted on thread: 25
----NestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION
---AsyncVoidMethod EXCEPTION
-----MoreNestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION
----NestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION
-----MoreNestedAsyncVoid EXCEPTION


This breaks if the async void method itself calls an async void method, or otherwise starts a nested operation that completes before it does.

@Servy thanks for the hint - will try to fix it. Currently rethinking a lot of the implementation (want to really forward to a captured context in Post).  I was a bit too optimistic seems like, but don't think it's truly impossible (maybe it is).

Great! It seems to work.
Is this call very important:
// fake async to avoid possible dead-locks
await Task.Run(() => asyncSyncContext.WaitForCompletion());

@Ryebread it is to avoid a dead-lock if we are on the same thread (example we test for some reason on the main thread with WPF). You can make it synchronous asyncSyncContext.WaitForCompletion(); with the SingleThreadSynchronizationContext and see for yourself. Haven't tested in WPF tbh, don't know what your testing setup there is, but I assume it will dead-lock too.

if i don't call await Task.Run(() => asyncSyncContext.WaitForCompletion()); the test method will finish before the async void calls have finished. So it is very important.

yes. Exactly. I assumed you can have your test methods async themselves to be able to await and the issue was async void not being awaitable. What my code does is essentially just turn an async void in async Task with all nested exceptions (which may be modified to turn off).

the point is that if you are running your tests on the Main Thread and you block by either having asyncContext.WaitForCompletion() or RunAsync...GetAwaiter().GetResult()...then the continuations that may need to be scheduled on the same thread can't run because we block there. And we won't return until all continuations are run til the end. So a dead-lock will occur.

you are really supposed to use the API I gave you with the static class and the static RunAsync method?, i.e. await AsyncVoidRunner.RunAsync(AsyncVoidMethod, true);

I will accept this answer, it is really well thought out. I think there is room for improvement: 1. avoiding making test methods async 2. Avoiding any kind of Complete ()/ Wait() call at the end of each test. But maybe that's asking for too much.

Your question is about Unit testing async void (fire-and-forget) methods, and my reason for ▲ you is that this scenario is particularly crucial in a test environment like MSTest, where evaluating asynchronous UI interactions in platforms like WPF or Winforms is often complex and fraught with challenges. These tests might involve stimuli that are either test-driven or interactively user-driven. They may also require monitoring for changes in typically synchronous methods like OnPropertyChanged, or tracking updates in a continuously running polling loop.
You go on to state:

My goal is to run this code synchronously during tests. Is this possible?

While it may be possible, it might not be optimal. Depending on the specific code, taking methods that were designed to be asynchronous and running them synchronously generally carries some risk of deadlock, especially if one async method causes another to run in parallel. With this in mind, I’d like to suggest an alternative approach to your SynchronousSynchronizationContext class for testing async void methods.
This is a tried and true approach that I've used extensively for testing my UI application in "just the basic" MSTest environment. My early attempts always seemed to pile additional timing uncertainties on top of the ones I was trying to test. This solution is dirt simple. I made a helper class that exposes an extension for object that fires a custom static event automatically tagged with the caller method name. There's also an args property that can carry a Dictionary<string, object> or a json payload (for example), and this is to provide context to the MSTest method that is listening to it, plus you have the sender object itself. Taken together, this provides a rich context in which to evaluate this moment in the app's asynchronous life.
One of the simplest examples I can think of would be the ability to await an expected property change from within the synchronous System.Windows.Window.OnPropertyChanged() method in the app under test. You can do this by adding one line to call the OnAwaited extension:
App under test
// <PackageReference Include="IVSoftware.Portable.Threading" Version="*" />
// using IVSoftware.Portable.Threading;
// The synchronous method you want to observe but can't (or shouldn't) call directly. 
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    this.OnAwaited(new AwaitedEventArgs(args: new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { nameof(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs), e }
    }));
}

MSTest
In the test method, the static Awaited event is subscribed just for the duration of this particular test. Once it's raised, it can be inspected to see who the sending object is, to see what method actually called it, and to examine whatever rich treasures have been pushed into the args object for detailed analysis.

Perhaps I should emphasize that while the event 'is' static, in a non-parallel test execution there would typically be just the one "local listener" at a time subscribed for that brief test. For example, the goal might be to test that the database write triggers the cloud update, and that the method that is polling for loopback changes from the cloud will ultimately detect that the record change was acknowledged and we're waiting for that third thing to happen.

// using static IVSoftware.Portable.Threading.Extensions;
[TestMethod]
public async Task MyTest_ReturnsData()
{
    SemaphoreSlim awaiter = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    string? actual = null;
    try
    {
        Awaited += localOnAwaited;

        WPFAppWindow?.CallSomeAsyncVoidMethod();
        // Wait for it to have a deterministic
        // effect after a non-deteministic time.
        Assert.IsTrue(
            condition: await awaiter.WaitAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)),
            "Timed out waiting for property change.");
        Assert.AreEqual(
            expected: "MyExpectedValue",
            actual: actual,
            $"An unexpected value was detected in {nameof(WPFAppWindow)}.OnPropertyChanged().");
    }
    finally
    {
        // CRITICAL to unconditionally unsubscribe
        // from the static method when done.
        Awaited -= localOnAwaited;
    }
    #region L o c a l M e t h o d s
    void localOnAwaited(object? sender, AwaitedEventArgs e)
    {
                object? o;
                switch (e.Caller)
                {
                    // Very common scenario of listening for a
                    // property to change after a UI stimulus.
                    case "OnPropertyChanged":
                        if (e.Args is Dictionary<string, object> args)
                        {
                            if (args.TryGetValue(nameof(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs), out o) &&
                            o is DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs wpfPropertyChanged)
                            {
                                switch (wpfPropertyChanged.Property.Name)
                                {
                                    case "MyTargetProperty":
                                        // The property we've been listening to has changed.
                                        actual = $"{wpfPropertyChanged.NewValue}";
                                        awaiter.Release();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
    }
    #endregion L o c a l M e t h o d s
}


I did want to mention the demonstration WPF application on the GitHub home page for the NuGet package. It showcases a practical use case by implementing a sample UI and demonstrating MSTest routines. Feel free to Clone or Browse.
Screenshots from the demo app



I see a downvote and I promise I'm not whining about that, but my humble request is that if you tried this and it didn't work, please let me know what went wrong! My reputation IRL is on the line because this extension is published as a NuGet. I've used it over and over again for years in some very complex scenarios and consider it free of operating bugs. I thought it would be non-controversial to offer it as an alternative for managing this problem domain. I'd be very grateful to understand what the specific objection is. THX!

(I didn't downvote you) - but I can see how your static event Awaited is going to cause problems (as-is) because the code you posted isn't thread-safe (even worse: MSTestV2 runs tests in parallel, concurrently, in the same AppDomain (if on .NET 4.x) - your SemaphoreSlim is a local - not a static - so this doesn't bode well.

What I observe MSTest doing when the [TestMethod] is declared async Task is 'not' executing the tests in parallel, however. I have over 100 UI tests and have never seen any conflicts of two tests running concurrently. That said, I understand that sometimes you want to make sure that concurrency is happening and you're specifically testing that. But I see no evidence of that occurring inadvertently in the manner it's coded in the demo app or my production app.

IIRC, you need to be using MSTestV2 and you need the "Run tests in parallel" option enabled in Test Explorer - also consider doing multi-targeting for both .NET Fx 4.8 and .NET 6+.

Dai Thx! Based on your feedback, I tried to get into trouble by turning on [Run Tests in Parallel]. Nothing there, and I see nothing inherently unsafe about invoking the static Awaited delegate. Demo code doesn't read or write any memory that could be changed by another thread concurrently. As far as local SemaphoreSlim, it's analogous to being in an oauth flow and starting a localhost to listen for the token callback. I would add a Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) in OnPropertyChanged, because if you're not on the UI thread there you've got bigger problems than this.

That said, the repo code would show (but it isn't posted here) that calls to something like WPFAppWindow?.CallSomeAsyncVoidMethod() are marshaled on the client side, not on the MSTest side, as a courtesy to the test writer who doesn't have to worry about calling WPFAppWindow?.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>CallSomeAsyncVoidMethod()) each and every time. I think you're raising good points but I do have a fair amount of understanding and experience with async programming and, until there's evidence to the contrary, stand by my claim that it's going to be a robust strategy overall. Thx Dai!

"stand by my claim that it's going to be a robust strategy overall" - whereas I'll get the popcorn ready for when @StephenCleary will inevitably find this and post a reply

I'm here to learn! And I've learned a ton from Stephen for sure. My test engineering career (SPT, Fairchild, Linear, Analog) is mostly behind me, and I'm no longer tasked i.e. with UI based constrained random verification using Linduino for automotive Battery Management Systems. Nobody makes me write code in MFC or ActiveX anymore. But, I still love to party! If a future testable case proves this answer erroneous or bad, I'm going to want to correct or remove it for sure.
